# How to find the actual tree depth for XG-Boost regressor model in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I want to find the number of tree depth, number of leaves actually assigned in my xgboot regression model.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50426248/how-to-know-the-number-of-tree-created-in-xgboost

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know the number of tree created in XGBoost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50426248/how-to-know-the-number-of-tree-created-in-xgboost)

Comment: (How to know the number of tree created in XGBoost)---> This gives the number of trees in the forest. But I would like to know the depth of each tree.

Answer (score 2):

To get this information you need to get the [booster](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html) object back, I assume you are using the scikit-learn interface, so for example using a model with 3 estimators (trees) and a maximum depth of 7:

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X,y = make_classification(random_state=99)
clf = xgb.XGBModel(objective='binary:logistic',n_estimators = 3,max_depth = 7)
clf.fit(X,y)
```

In this case, we pull out the object and also covert the tree information to a dataframe:

```
booster = clf.get_booster()

tree_df = booster.trees_to_dataframe()
tree_df[tree_df['Tree'] == 0]

    Tree    Node    ID  Feature Split   Yes No  Missing Gain    Cover
0   0   0   0-0 f11 -0.233068   0-1 0-2 0-1 48.161629   25.00
1   0   1   0-1 f1  -1.081945   0-3 0-4 0-3 0.054384    9.25
2   0   2   0-2 f14 0.480458    0-5 0-6 0-5 8.410727    15.75
3   0   3   0-3 Leaf    NaN NaN NaN NaN -0.150000   1.00
4   0   4   0-4 Leaf    NaN NaN NaN NaN -0.535135   8.25
5   0   5   0-5 f18 0.261421    0-7 0-8 0-7 5.638095    6.50
6   0   6   0-6 f9  -1.585489   0-9 0-10    0-9 0.727795    9.25
7   0   7   0-7 f18 -0.640538   0-11    0-12    0-11    4.342857    4.00
8   0   8   0-8 f0  0.072811    0-13    0-14    0-13    1.028571    2.50
9   0   9   0-9 Leaf    NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.163636    1.75
10  0   10  0-10    Leaf    NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.529412    7.50
11  0   11  0-11    Leaf    NaN NaN NaN NaN -0.120000   1.50
12  0   12  0-12    Leaf    NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.428571    2.50
13  0   13  0-13    Leaf    NaN NaN NaN NaN -0.000000   1.00
14  0   14  0-14    Leaf    NaN NaN NaN NaN -0.360000   1.50
```

Visualizing the first tree. The depth of a decision tree is the number of splits from a root to a leaf, so this tree has a depth of 4 :

```
xgb.plotting.plot_tree(booster, num_trees=0)
```

[image]

Maybe there's a better solution, but quickly I used the [solution from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028979/recursive-iteration-through-nested-json-for-specific-key-in-python), to iterate through the json output and calculate the depth of each tree:

```
def item_generator(json_input, lookup_key):
    if isinstance(json_input, dict):
        for k, v in json_input.items():
            if k == lookup_key:
                yield v
            else:
                yield from item_generator(v, lookup_key)
    elif isinstance(json_input, list):
        for item in json_input:
            yield from item_generator(item, lookup_key)

def tree_depth(json_text):
    json_input = json.loads(json_text)
    return max(list(item_generator(json_input, 'depth'))) + 1

[tree_depth(x) for x in booster.get_dump(dump_format = "json")]

[4, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using XGBoost regressor, it says attribute error. (No attribute 'get_dump' in XGBoost regressor).   Also, for tree to data frame conversion I used (booster.get_booster().trees_to_dataframe())

Comment: I think that since each node is only split by 2, we can take the `np.log2` of the number of nodes per tree, no?